# String Concatenation v JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, typescript, concatenation

In Javascript, what's the difference between creating a string with jQuery v concatenation? Is there some sort of ulterior performance or convention reason to prefer one over the other?

```
const myvar = "hello world";
const strQuery = "${myvar} is cool";
const strConcat = myvar + " is cool";
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in the code here

Comment: theres no jquery here.

Comment: Oh! The linked urls helped. I think I mistook templating with JQuery, and it turned me around.

Thanks for the speedy responses.